# <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="73400320" /> with .net core app using docker containers

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have set the property:

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="73400320" />
```

In my .net core app, however when i run my app inside of a docker container it doesn't seem to be looking at this setting which is in my web config fie, i'm guessing docker doesn't need this file as the app is hosted using the kestrel?

in my .net core 2.2 app, i cannot upload a file bigger than 30mb( the default max file size) when i run this on docker, this all works fine when i am not using docker.

Is there a configuration i need to do to change this within docker.

Comment: Tried `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536"/>` ?

Comment: `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536"/>` is for `ASP.NET`

Answer (score 1):

The `web.config` file applys to the classic IIS stack, which only works on Windows. Using Docker, you're running the new platform-independent Kestrel webserver introducued with ASP.NET Core.

### Global

To set the limit globally on every request (which seems the equivalent of your IIS setting), simply set the property by adding `.UseKestrel` with the corresponding options in `Program.CreateWebHostBuilder` like this:

```
.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) => {
    serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 73400320;
});
```

You can find all configuration options [in the ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#kestrel-options). Dont forget to set your ASP.NET Core version on the left. This is important because the API may has changed, e.g. from 2.1 to 2.2.

### Local

Alternatively, it's also possible to just increase it for certain actions by using data annotations:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(73400320)]
public IActionResult MyActionMethod() { 
    // ... 
}
```

### How to prevent those surprises in the future

This problem is likely caused by Visual Studio, which is automatically setting IIS as default webserver instead of Kestrel. So you're using IIS during local development and Kestrel when hosting on Docker. Sadly, this is not 100% intuitive in VS. You need to check the context menu popping out when clicking on the arrow near the debug button like this:

[image]

*IrCms* is dynamically replaced by your applications project name. If this is selected, you get Kestrel during debug. So the project on the screenshot is well configured for Kestrel. Could be verified by an console window, that got opened and say *listen on port XYZ* after debugging.

The IIS doesn't open any window. Just it's icon will appear left to your clock in the taskbar:

[image]

The first thing I'm usually doing on new ASP.NET Core projects is changing IIS to Kestrel. I'd recommend this especially when deploying to Docker, so you're always use the same webserver. In general, Kestrel is a lightweight alternative to consider, when no special features of them are required.

Comment: Awesome, this fixed my problem thank you very much!